# How to embed a manual loss function in keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a desired loss function as:

```
one_weight = (1-num_of_ones)/(num_of_ones + num_of_zeros)
zero_weight = (1-num_of_zeros)/(num_of_ones + num_of_zeros)

def weighted_binary_crossentropy(zero_weight, one_weight):

    def weighted_binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):    
        b_ce = K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)    
        # weighted calc
        weight_vector = y_true * one_weight + (1 - y_true) * zero_weight
        weighted_b_ce = weight_vector * b_ce   
        return K.mean(weighted_b_ce)

return weighted_binary_crossentropy
```

I'm trying to use this loss function in my model which is:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(32,1),strides=(1,1), activation='relu', input_shape=(78,64,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(1,10),strides=(1,10), activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(ReLU(max_value=None))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
 
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss =  weighted_binary_crossentropy , metrics = ['acc'] )

history = model.fit(Train_Data, Train_labels, batch_size =20, epochs = 450, shuffle = True , validation_data = (Val_Data, Val_labels))
```

my question is, the loss function requires an input which is `y_pred` (the labels of test data which are predicted by model). `y_pred` is accessible after training the model by my desired loss function, but the loss function requires `y_pred` during training the model.

On the other hand, I can say: I use the loss function to train my model but it gives error, because there is no `y_pred` to use it as input of loss function.

How can i use my desired loss function to train the model while I don't have `y_pred` before starting the training process? note that I have other required loss function parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass your own parameters to `weighted_binary_crossentropy`. This function returns internal wrapped function (`weighted_binary_crossentropy`) which accepts `y_true` and `y_pred` and you don't need to do anything with it.

```
model.compile(optimizer=opt, 
              loss=weighted_binary_crossentropy(zero_weight,one_weight),
              metrics=['acc'])
```

Comment: Thank you Kaveh. Damet garm